# Java/Eclipse swaps parameter order in method call, giving an error

Tags: java, eclipse

This code:

```
temp.set(pizzaArray.get(i), upIdx);
```

refers to this method (in my ArrayList class):

```
    public void set(T objectToSet, int index) {
    this.data[index] = objectToSet;
}
```

It generates an error "The method set(int, Pizza) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Pizza, int).

This is a home-grown ArrayList class, not Java's built-in one. temp is an ArrayList. I've checked everything I can think of and restarted Eclipse; why does Java insist that my set method wants the arguments in reverse order?

Comment: Please format your code properly in order to make it more readable.

Comment: Did you try to clean you project?

Comment: I hadn't but tried cleaning and it didn't help

Comment: "... checked everything I can think of ...." -- this is why you are often asked to boil down your code to the extent that you can and then post everything.  The chances of this being "swapped" by Java or eclipse or anything else are much smaller than the chances of you not understanding what part of your code you don't understand.  We can't help you understand it without more information

Comment: I noticed that Java's built-in ArrayList had the parameters in the reverse order from mine, so I renamed the method from set to setElementAtIndex. Now the error message is "The method setElementAtIndex(Pizza, int) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Pizza>.

Comment: What is the meaning of `home grown`, selfmade? Please post the relevant code. 
Espacially the defininition and usage of all arrays and ArrayLists.
As of my experience, IDEs and compilers don't lie.

Comment: If your teacher wants you to implement an array-list and call it `ArrayList` this is an indication that he or she needs to read more about current practices. If you did that in any Java development shop I've worked in you would get reprimanded, for exactly the reasons you are asking the question in the first place. It is a name conflict and every developer who comes after you to maintain your code will curse your name to the end of time.  In fact your code would be immediately refactored to rename the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an import statement for the standard ArrayList, which Eclipse had "helpfully" hidden from me. When I expanded the import list, there it was. Removed it and all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have all your code, but it's obvious that your `temp` variable is referencing a normal java.util.ArrayList. Rename your "homegrown" ArrayList class to something different (`MyArrayList` for (a bad) example), and then reference an instance of that class

```
MyArrayList<Pizza> temp = new MyArrayList<>();
```

That should solve your issues.

If you want to keep your ArrayList name, then as long as there are no `import java.util.ArrayList` statements on top of your file, then the compiler will refer to your ArrayList, not java.util's.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think my teacher would be happy with that. Surely there must be some way to eliminate the ambiguity?

Comment: Make sure there are no `import java.util.ArrayList` statements on top of your file?